# Angular 7 child routes import component usando modules

Tags: angular, angular-routes, angular-module, angular-7

> Estou tentando setar algumas rotas filhas na minha aplicação angular 7 porém elas não funcionam, tenho o seguinte cenário:

Possuo um `base-home.component` e um `home.component`, encapsulei os dois components em modules específicos de cada um, `base-home.module` e `home.module`, importei os dois módulos no `app.module`, e setei no `app-routing.module` umas rota `'/'` que chama o `base-home.component`, e uma rota filha `'/home'` que chama o `home.component`, porém ele não carrega a página, porém se eu importar os components direto no `app.module` em vez de importar os modules eles funciona, segue como estão os arquivos:

```js
// app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { BaseHomeModule } from './base-home/base-home.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BaseHomeModule,
    HomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
// app-routing.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { BaseHomeComponent } from './base-home/base-home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BaseHomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent 
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```js
// base-home.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BaseHomeComponent } from './base-home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      BaseHomeComponent
  ],
  exports: [
      BaseHomeComponent
    ]
})
export class BaseHomeModule {}
```

```js
// home.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      HomeComponent
  ],
  exports: [
      HomeComponent
    ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Dessa maneira acima ele não funciona, mas se eu importar o `base-home.component` direto no no `app.module` ele funciona, dessa forma:

```js
// app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { BaseHomeComponent } from './base-home/base-home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BaseHomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer as child routes funcionar importando apenas os modules com os components encapsulados sem precisar importar o component direto no `app-module` ?

Answer (score 1):

No seu `app.module.ts` tente trocar o atributo 'component' pelo 'loadChildren', ficando algo como:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { BaseHomeComponent } from './base-home/base-home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BaseHomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule', // <<<<<<<
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Referenciando diretamente o caminho do módulo você não precisa importar nem o `HomeModule` nem o `HomeComponent` no seu `AppModule`.

Comment: eu fiz do jeito que disse, mas não funcionou, ele diz `router-outlet is not a know element`

Comment: Se você não está usando o `router-outlet` então não vejo motivo para ter encapsulado os componentes em módulos específicos. Você poderia simplesmente usar os componentes sem criação de módulos e chamar `home.component` no seu `app.module` como já havia feito antes.